# Cucumber feature file - describe aggregation

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I am new in the cucumber world and i just want to describe an aggregation for the context of my scenario. I have a model and a DataTransferObject like the one below and i want to write an REST Api which returns a JSON.

```
public class Product {
  int id;
  String name;
  double basePrice;
  ProductCategory category;
}

public class ProductCategory {
  int id;
  String name;
  List<Customization> possibleCustomizationsForCategory;
}

public class Customization {
  int id;
  String characteristic;
  double additionalPrice;
}

public class ProductDTO {
  int productId;
  String productName;
  double basePrice;
  Size size;
  int productCategoryId;
  String productCategoryName;
  List<Integer> possibleCustomizationIds;
}
```

I want to write something like this:

```
Given the system has persisted the following products
When a client requests GET /products
Then he will receive a JSON like the following:
  """
   [
    {
     "productId": 1,
     "productName": "Kaffee",
     "basePrice": 2.00,
     "size": "SMALL",
     "productCategoryId": 1,
     "productCategoryName": "Hot Drinks",
     "possibleCustomizationIds": [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    },
    {
     "productId": 2,
     "productName": "Kaffee",
     "basePrice": 3.0,
     "size": "MEDIUM",
     "productCategoryId": 1,
     "productCategoryName": "Hot Drinks",
     "possibleCustomizationIds": [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    }
    {
     "productId": 3,
     "productName": "Cookie",
     "basePrice": 1.0,
     "size": "SMALL",
     "productCategoryId": 1,
     "productCategoryName": "Biscuite",
     "possibleCustomizationIds": [8,9]
    }
   ]
  """
```

But how can I write the Given part and describe the Object in a way that it will be clear that there are three different classes with aggregations?

Answer (score 0):

I would keep Gherkin in a more business level language that describes the problem you are trying to solve.

I would then have the step definitions describe the solution to the problem.

Therefore, your gherkin could be:

```
Given the following products are in stock
   | Product       |
   | Small Kaffee  |
   | Medium Kaffee |
   | Small Cookie  |
When I get a list of stock
Then I the three products should be shown as in stock
And I should be able to view the details about them
```

I have assumed this is a stock control situation. This Scenario could then be ran against a database, web api, or the GUI and should still be true, just will a different solution in place.. i.e. using different step definitions.